# How to remove the focus on a form field when the user presses up or down arrow key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with autofocus of search form field. I want to remove the focus on the form field when a user presses up or down arrow key so that he can scroll down the page without clicking anywhere on the page. A perfect example of this kind of UX is www.quora.com. How do i do that?

I have tried doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#search").blur();
   });
</script>
```

But, it just removes the focus immediately after the page loads. How do i make it lose focus only when the user presses up or down arrow keys?

My html form field is as follows:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" type="text" style="border-right:0" autofocus>
   <span class="input-group-addon search-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried so far that is not working.

Comment: With jQuery use key.press arrow up 33 and arrow down 34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this jQuery :

With `autofocus`

```
$(function(){
  $('#search').keydown(function (e) { 
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
          if(code==38  || code==40){ 
           $(this).focusout(); 
         }

  });
});
```

Without `autofocus`

```
    $(function(){
  $(document).keyup(function (e) { 
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
          if(code!=38  && code!=40){ 
           $('#search').focus(); 
         }

  });
});
```

Arrow Up : 38

Arrow Down: 40

You have to handle `keyup` event of user.

Form:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" type="text" style="border-right:0">
   <span class="input-group-addon search-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2655764 post you `html search form`

Comment: It works if i press the down arrow button twice. Maybe because it is keyup. How do i make it work when the user presses the up or down arrow for the first time?

Comment: @user2655764 may be user first press is used to focus the search box, and second press for other event. For first press your should replace this  `$("#myInput")` to `$(document)`

Comment: @user2655764 give your site url or post search form html